# Raspberry Pi 3 b+ - Ehternet port is not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Raspberry Pi 3B+ I have connected by mistake 5v pin to 5v pin. I was connecting a fan to my Raspberry Pi 3B+ which was presented with a connector.

But since then my raspberry pi ethernet is not working. Did I reset any setting or something actually went terribly wrong. Not sure, but it seems like its not working. Nor I am not able to connect it with WiFi. I have installed Hassbian on it and as per its documentation

https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/installation/hassbian/installation/

I just created a file `wpa_supplicant.conf` in boot folder through SD card reader. And I am not able to open the Pi board to troubleshoot the issue as I don't have any remote connectivity.

Someone can suggest the issue I might be having? I have red light working on it. Also I tried installing new OS on another SD Card but still it was also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it sounds like you fried your board...

Comment: But my red LED is blinking.

Comment: It's not blinking actually. It's just ON constantly.